# Proving $f(x)=cx$ for constant $c$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t (f(x+y)-f(y))\,dy \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

> If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{t}\displaystyle\int_0^t (f(x+y)-f(y))\,dy \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall t>0$, then show that there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=cx \forall x$

Does this have anything to do with Cauchy's functional equation $f(x)=f(x+y)-f(y)$ which also gives the same solution for $f$?

Comment: Yes. Multiply both sides by $t$, then differentiate with respect to $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in a comment: since this holds for all $t>0$, you have the equivalent formulation
$$
t f(x)= \int_0^t (f(x+y)-f(y))\,dy \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \forall t > 0 \tag{1}
$$
which implies, by differentiating with regard to $t$:
$$
f(x)= f(x+t)-f(t) \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \forall t >0 \tag{2}
$$
which is exactly [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) (recall that $f$ is also assumed continuous in our case). Hence, any solution to (1) must be a solution to (2), and we know the latter: $f\colon x\mapsto cx$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. It only remains to check that indeed these solutions satisfy (1); which is immediate.

Comment: There is a small caveat, as Cauchy's functional equation would not require that $t>0$; this won't change the proof, however.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming f is infinitely differentiable. (so it is a bit out of scope)

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \frac{d(f(x+y)-f(y))}{dx}\,dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f'(x+y)\,dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{t} (f(x+t)-f(x))$$
$$=f'(x)+\frac{f''(x)}{2}t+...$$

$$\rightarrow f''(x)=0$$

$$\rightarrow f'(x)=constant$$

$$\rightarrow f(x)=cx + constant$$

Comment: Unless the constant is zero, there will be a problem.

Comment: You don't need anything more than the third line of your equation  where you get $f(x+t)=f(x)+t\,f'(x)$ (hence, you only need to assume that $f$ is differentiable).  That means already that $f$ is linear with slope $f'(x)$ on any interval $[x,\infty)$.  It follows immediately that $f'$ must be constant.  To write the fourth line, you are adding a very strong assumption---$f$ is analytic.

Comment: @ClementC. Posted answer. So, is the constant indeed zero?

Comment: @Batominovski Posted answer based on your comment and user115350's answer

Answer (score 0):

Assume f is differentiable

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \frac{d(f(x+y)-f(y))}{dx}\,dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f'(x+y)\,dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{t} (f(x+t)-f(x))$$

$$\to f'(x)=\frac{1}{t} (f(x+t)-f(x))$$

$$\to \exists c \ \in \ \mathbb R \ \text{s.t.} \ f'(x)=c$$

$$\to f(x)=cx+d$$

Find d:

$$cx+d = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t (c(x+y)+d - cy - d) dy $$

$$\to cx+d = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t (cx) dy$$

$$\to cx+d = (cx) \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t  dy$$

$$\to cx+d = (cx)$$

$$\to d=0$$

---

Otherwise:

See Clement C.'s answer:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1859672/140308